# Ubuntu Software Center's history is showing software which i have not installed

Tags: software-center

I am running Linux for the first time and have installed Ubuntu 12.10, 64-bit OS on my laptop, alongside Windows 7. My question may be a stupid one since I am yet to begin discovering all of Ubuntu's features. The Software Center's History Section on my Ubuntu is showing a large list of files (software), installed on 17 October 2012, at 09:28 AM. I have never really installed any software from that list. I would like to know what exactly is that large list of files? Sorry if this is a naive question...

Here's a link to the screenshot: [Screenshot of my Software Center's History Section](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=360f652)

Comment: Not possible to answer without knowing what is in your list ;) Why not upload a picture of it somewhere and post the url in your topic?

Comment: My feeling is that these files were installed as part of the 12.10 installation itself and nothing to worry about. 12.10 was released on 18 Oct 2012.

Comment: @Rinzwind i have added the screenshot... please have a look..

Answer (score 0):

I think you must install ubuntu using LiveCD.

Installing Linux with LiveCD is something like installing Windows using Ghost_CD/DVD.

So the softwares you saw in Software Center's history were installed by the Canonical before the company packed the whole ubuntu system up and made it into LiveCD.

Comment: i had installed ubuntu from its website...

Comment: @anujit that is not possible ;) You burn a cd/dvd to install ;)

Comment: no dude.. its from ubuntu.com...i have used the windows installer.. [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)

Comment: @anujit...If you download the LiveCD, you will find the windows installer(wubi.exe) in it. The website saves you the step of downloading the ISO but downloads every thing in the ISO while installing instead. That's to say: Installing by wubi.exe is equal to that by LiveCD.